# Excel increment cell reference dynamically and fill the result data

Tags: excel

I have the following scenario in excel,

In `Sheet1` I have the following values,

cell **A1** is 5

cell **B1** is 5

and in `Sheet2` I want the sum in cell **C1** . So I do this at Sheet2 C1 cell:

```
=SUM(Sheet1!A1:B1)
```

This works as expected.

But, I want the C1 to increment dynamically based on the change in Sheet1 A1 and B1 values.

**For example:**

If in Sheet1 I change values of A1 to 10 and B1 to 10.
C1 in Sheet2 will be changed to 20 which is expected.

But I want the result 20 to be filled in Sheet2 C2 ( increment cell reference if not empty).

Similarly, if A1 and B1 changed again in Sheet1 result should be in C3 Of Sheet2 and it goes on.

What’s the correct way to achieve this ?

Comment: This can only be achieved programmatically (e.g. using VBA).

Comment: What does this statement mean: "if A1 and B1 changed again in Sheet1"? Does it mean that you change A1, nothing happens, but when you change B1, something should be done (and what in case B1 changes but A1 has not been changed?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more or less what it should look like:

Source code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
    Sheet2.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheet1.Range("A1") + Sheet1.Range("B1")
  End If
End Sub
```

VBA editor screenshot:

[image]